# Tips on designing a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join

I am designing a mysql database for a listing website. This is my first time and I did some googling on this:)
I wanted to cross check if there is any problems in my approach.

So basically, I will have 5 tables. Lets say

1. Studio (Actual studio data points)
2. Studio Facilities (Like, transport, water etc)
3. Studio Images
4. Studio Reviews. (Name, stars, etc..)
5. Location & Locality (City,City Direction,Locality e.g Bangalore, North Bangalore, Hebbal).

So Studio table will hold the master record. Facilities, images and reviews will hold data by using studio as FK.
Location ID will be saved on the studio record.

My question now is that if I want to show a listing of all hebbal studios, I will have to perform a join of all 5 tables to show the studio data, images, reviews and facilities.

1) Is this ok? Do you see any potential problems with this approach? Are there any better approaches?
2) will the query execution time increase as the number of records increase?

Thanks

Comment: in location, there should be fields for latitude and longitude

Comment: Yes, I will add them on the studio table itself. The location table will be used for filtering

Comment: @Strawberry, I have read that by indexing columns which will be used for where clauses , speed can be improved, but i guess as time goes and number of records increase, query time is bound to increase right?..

Comment: @Strawberry, lets suppose i split the studio tables into multiple tables for each category, i guess that should help in the long run??

Comment: Yes. But worry about that when it happens.

Comment: No. That will make things worse

Comment: regarding splitting the table into multiple tables for each category, can you please elaborate on how it will make it worse. This is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a solid approaches, databases are designed to use joins and those are appropriate. Denormalization will cause more problems especially concerning data integrity than your current design,

Will the queries get slower with more data? Of course they will but that is true of any design. Sending 10 gig of data back across the network or internet is going to be slower than sending 10 bytes.

You don't ask but are there things you can do to prevent the queries from getting unacceptably slower? Yes. First you need to make sure that Foreign key and fields that will appear frequently in the where clause are indexed as well as the PKs. This will be enough to prevent horrible performance for most simple queries.

Another thing you should do is read a good book on performance tuning for the particular database backend you are using. Most of the ones I have read have at least one chapter on designing queries for performance. Read it and re-read it and re-read it until this is sunk into your bones and you would not consider writing queries any other way.

Many databases are considered slow because their developers are incompetent at writing performant queries and the joins get blamed. Learn about sargabilty. Understand how indexes work and what the tradeoffs for having them are. Understand how wide you table can be before performance suffers  (Hint sometimes two tables in a one-one relationship are faster than using one table with the table would  be very wide.).

You cannot effectively design a database without a solid grounding in performance tuning.

Answer (score -1):

You can use one master table (here it is *Studio*) and can use reference keys to all other tables.

It is always better to split up the tables for [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization).

Benefits of normalization

- Eliminate data redundancy
- Improve performance
- Query optimization
- Faster update due to less number of columns in one table
- Index improvement

Research normalization and you will get good idea to build DB.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that. Studio is my master table, Studio Images, Facilities and Reviews will use studio_id as foriegn key reference. <br> My concern is that as the number of rows increase, will it over time, increase the query execution time?

Comment: That is good. You can design DB as system module wise aslo.Here you can go ahead.

Comment: visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization , http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm

Comment: I think the op understands the basic concept of normalisation.